# How to iterate over a string of numbers / special characters in java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

For example, take a string: `"33 4 / 44 2 - ^"`

I'm using Scanner to iterate over the ints but once there is no `nextInt` and it hits a special character, how would I go about "getting" that character and then moving onto the next int/special character?

Comment: You should be using a _stack_ here if you want to evaluate your expression, which appears to be in reverse Polish notation.  There are many examples of this on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if there's a `int` available using `hasNextInt()`. If there isn't, just discard the next token by calling `next()`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("33 4 / 44 2 - ^");
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        int nextInt = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(nextInt);
    } else {
        // discard next token
        scanner.next();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
33
4
44
2
```

Comment: say I wanted to get that char. Would I simply use c = sc.next()?

Comment: That would give you the next whitespace-delimited string. If you know it's only 1 char long, you can get `sc.next().charAt(0)`.

Comment: is there a way to do that as a string rather than a char? Or is the only way to convert that to string?

Comment: oh oops my bad. Thank you.

Comment: Hi I'd like to follow up. I need to get the char (/ or - or ^) within the string (that consists of all the ints) AS a string. I tried [if (!sc.hasNextInt()) { String.valueOf(sc.next());] although I do not think it's working. I'd be great if you could help.